# System.StackOverflowException in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, integer, unhandled-exception, mscorlib

I am receiving

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll'

error when I run the below code. I cannot figure out where I have gone wrong and how to rectify it. Can anybody help me with this?

The code is supposed to filter through a list of integers, which ever group of the given integers match a target number; the group of integers are put into a List and then that list is put into another list for the process to continue with the remaining numbers.

Any and all help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
    List<List<int>> results = null;
    public void Listing(List<int> numbers)
    {
        int target = Convert.ToInt32(textBox15.Text);
        Solver solver = new Solver();
        results = solver.Solve(target, numbers.ToArray());
    }
    public class Solver
    {
        private List<List<int>> mResults;
        int t = 0;
        public List<List<int>> Solve(int goal, int[] elements)
        {
            int t = goal;
            mResults = new List<List<int>>();
            RecursiveSolve(goal, 0, new List<int>(), new List<int>(elements), 0);
            return mResults;
        }
        private void RecursiveSolve(int goal, int currentSum, List<int> included, List<int> notIncluded, int startIndex)
        {
            List<int> nextIncluded = new List<int>(included);
            List<int> nextNotIncluded = new List<int>(notIncluded);
            try
            {
                for (int index = startIndex; index < notIncluded.Count; index++)
                {
                    int nextValue = notIncluded[index];
                    if (currentSum + nextValue == t)
                    {
                        List<int> newResult = new List<int>(included);
                        newResult.Add(nextValue);
                        mResults.Add(newResult);
                        t = goal;
                    }
                    else if (currentSum + nextValue < t)
                    {
                        nextIncluded.Add(nextValue);
                        nextNotIncluded.Remove(nextValue);
                        RecursiveSolve(t, currentSum + nextValue, nextIncluded, nextNotIncluded, startIndex++);
                    }
                    else if (currentSum + nextValue > t)
                    {
                        nextNotIncluded.Remove(nextValue);
                        nextNotIncluded.Add(nextValue);
                        t = t - 50;
                        RecursiveSolve(t, currentSum + nextValue, nextIncluded, nextNotIncluded, startIndex++);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Message : " + ex, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a tip for mathematical problems: In Visual Studio right click on project -> select 'Properties'. In 'Properties' choose 'Build' and on very bottom click on 'Advanced'. In 'Advanced' window check/mark the 'Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow', save and then try to run you application again

Comment: I don't fully understand what's happening, but look in your third `else` block: is this correct: `nextNotIncluded.Remove(nextValue); nextNotIncluded.Add(nextValue);`? There seems something wrong. Guess first line should be `nextIncluded.Remove(nextValue)` instead of `nextNotIncluded...`

Comment: Thanks Jasper, unfortunately that didn't do much this time; i'm still getting the error.

Comment: Rene - This is correct, I wanted the next Value to be moved to the end of the list so although it didn't match the requirements this time it can still be used later.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 click on 'Debug' on the top then click 'Exceptions' in menu. In 'Exceptions' window click in 'Find' and search for SO in the list then check/mark it and run again

Comment: Hi Jasper, that doesn't work in this case either unfortunately

Comment: Try to debug the code one line at the time, stepping into the recursive method each time and inspecting the values. If that takes too long, e.g. due to the large input values. Try to add some logging and extend it until you see with what values and where at code endless recursion occurs. It is very hard for anyone to help you effectively without knowing your inputs and reproducing the issue itself.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks suspicious to me.  The "nextNotIncluded" list is not getting smaller, so you end up with infinite recursion.

```
 else if (currentSum + nextValue > t)
 {
     nextNotIncluded.Remove(nextValue); // ** Remove?
     nextNotIncluded.Add(nextValue);    // ** Add Back?
     t = t - 50;
     RecursiveSolve(t, currentSum + nextValue, nextIncluded, nextNotIncluded, startIndex++);
 }
```

Did you mean this?

```
 else if (currentSum + nextValue > t)
 {
     nextNotIncluded.Remove(nextValue); // remove from nextNotIncluded
     nextIncluded.Add(nextValue);       // add to nextIncluded
     t = t - 50;
     RecursiveSolve(t, currentSum + nextValue, nextIncluded, nextNotIncluded, startIndex++);
 }
```

Edit: aha, here's another problem.  In your Solver constructor, you are not setting the member variable `t`.  This may not fix the actual SO exception, but it'll get you closer.

```
public List<List<int>> Solve(int goal, int[] elements)
 {
      /*int*/ t = goal;
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your response. The original code is correct in the way that I want it to work. If the next value puts the currentsum over the goal then it cannot be used, so I wanted to remove it from the list and re-add it to the end of the list so it can be reused later, to see if the next value meets the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You guys were right about the area of the error, but not 100% correct.

I figured out the solution, thanks for your help. The problem seems to have been rectified when I didn't add 'nextValue' to the 'currentSum' when I called the 'RecursiveSolve' thread again.

```
 else if (currentSum + nextValue > t)
                {
                    nextNotIncluded.Remove(nextValue);
                    nextNotIncluded.Add(nextValue);
                    t = t - 50;
                    RecursiveSolve(t, currentSum + nextValue, nextIncluded, nextNotIncluded, startIndex++);
                }
```